# PyQt4 tooltip for overlap rect items

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

In my view, I have 2 rect items , which one of them included in the other.
I want to set a tooltip for both of them, so when mouse is on the common area I'll get the inner tooltip, else, I'll get the outer.
I already saw it's impossible to add 2 tooltips on the same area, but this case is different, because the rects are overlap by one direction ..

```
rect_item_inner = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem()
rect_item_outer = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem()
rect_item_inner.setToolTip("inner data")
rect_item_outer.setToolTip("outer data")
```

Comment: In which order are you adding the items? Because if you add the inner rectangle *before* the outer, you'll end up having the outer rectangle *above* the other, which is why you cannot see the tooltip for the smaller rectangle.

Comment: please provide a [mre]